# Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare doesn't accept password

Tags: password-recovery

I install Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare. It works about month. But now it doesn't accept password. Password correct 100%. What should i do?

Comment: If you reset the password and the same problem still occurs, please then [edit] this question to provide details. (If we close this as a duplicate, your edit will get it automatically considered for reopening.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reviewing the "Lost Password" documentation :  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Comment: On restart VMachine holding 'Shift' don't works

Comment: It is possible your boot delay is so small you are missing it - check this other recommendation  http://askubuntu.com/questions/30858/how-to-reset-lost-user-password-on-a-guest-on-vmware-server